# change value of a column with conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a **`dataframe`** as follow:

```
id months  notation    
1  03       A    
1  05       D    
1  07       C

3  04       D    
3  06       B    
3  10       B

4  04       C    
4  09       D    
4  10       E
```

My **problem** is that for each id where notation become `D at m` I need to replace all its other notation at `m+1..m+n to D`

**Results expected**

```
1  03       A    
1  05       D    
1  07       D

3  04       D    
3  06       D    
3  10       D

4  04       C    
4  09       D    
4  10       D
```

How can I proceed? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With base `R`you can do:

```
new.vec <- function(x) { 
  i <- match("D", x)
  if (!is.na(i)) x[i:length(x)] <- "D"
  return(x) 
}
dat$result <- ave(dat$notation, dat$id, FUN=new.vec)
dat
# > dat
#   id months notation result
# 1  1      3        A      A
# 2  1      5        D      D
# 3  1      7        C      D
# 4  3      4        D      D
# 5  3      6        B      D
# 6  3     10        B      D
# 7  4      4        C      C
# 8  4      9        D      D
# 9  4     10        E      D
```

**data:**

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = 
" id months  notation    
1  03       A    
1  05       D    
1  07       C
3  04       D    
3  06       B    
3  10       B
4  04       C    
4  09       D    
4  10       E")
```

The function `new.vec()` can also be used for `[.data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
setDT(dat)[, new.nota:= new.vec(notation), by=id]
```

or without defining a function:

```
setDT(dat)[, new.nota:={ i <- match("D", notation);  x <- notation; if(!is.na(i)) x[i:.N]<-"D"; x }, id][]
```

Comment: @Maha It was a typo. I edited the answer (should be `dat$id`).

Answer (score 6):

Another option with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table): *(edited to a suppress its flaw, thanks to @docendodiscimus)*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, min_mo:=min(months[notation=="D"]), by=id][months>=min_mo, notation:="D"][, min_mo:=NULL]

dat
#   id months notation
#1:  1      3        A
#2:  1      5        D
#3:  1      7        D
#4:  3      4        D
#5:  3      6        D
#6:  3     10        D
#7:  4      4        C
#8:  4      9        D
#9:  4     10        D
```

**Explanation:** You first compute the minimum month with "D" as notation by `id`, then you set `notation` to `"D"` for the rows that have a `months` higher than the min one with `notation` "D", finally, you remove the temporary variable containing the minimal month.

---

**EDIT:**
If you can have `id`s with no "D", you can use the slightly modified line:

```
setDT(dat)[, min_mo:=if(any(notation=="D")) min(months[notation=="D"]) else 20L, by=id][months>=min_mo, notation:="D"][, min_mo:=NULL]
```

***Test:***

```
dat[, notation:=LETTERS[1:9]]
dat[, min_mo:=if(any(notation=="D")) min(months[notation=="D"]) else 20L, by=id][months>=min_mo, notation:="D"][, min_mo:=NULL]
dat
#   id months notation
#1:  1      3        A
#2:  1      5        B
#3:  1      7        C
#4:  3      4        D
#5:  3      6        D
#6:  3     10        D
#7:  4      4        G
#8:  4      9        H
#9:  4     10        I
```

Comment: do i need to download a package to use setDT?

Comment: Yes. `setDT` is from the `data.table` package.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(rank = match(notation, unique(notation))) %>%
  mutate(rankD = rank[notation %in% "D"][1]) %>%
  mutate(notation = ifelse(!(notation %in% "D") & rank > rankD, "D", notation)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("rank")) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#      id months notation
#   <int>  <int> <chr>   
# 1     1      3 A       
# 2     1      5 D       
# 3     1      7 D       
# 4     3      4 D       
# 5     3      6 D       
# 6     3     10 D       
# 7     4      4 C       
# 8     4      9 D       
# 9     4     10 D
```

**Update**

As the comment pointed out, we can combine the three `mutate` calls to one.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(rank = match(notation, unique(notation)),
         rankD = rank[notation %in% "D"][1],
         notation = ifelse(!(notation %in% "D") & rank > rankD, "D", notation)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("rank")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Another option is to use `cumsum`, assuming that the data is ordered, as in the example:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(notation = ifelse(cumsum(notation == "D") > 0, "D", notation))
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "id months  notation    
1  03       A    
1  05       D    
1  07       C
3  04       D    
3  06       B    
3  10       B
4  04       C    
4  09       D    
4  10       E",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: just a side note: you can do the three mutate steps in one mutate call separated by comma

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks for your comment. I have a question. Does combining all these steps to one mutate call make the performance faster than using three mutate calls?

Comment: I can only guess and my guess is that there's a (very?) slight overhead each time you call `mutate`, so there might be a tiny advantage calling it only once. But from my point of view it simply looks a little cleaner

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thank you for your answer. I have this question for a while.

Comment: you're welcome. the best answer probably is to run some benchmarks on different sizes of data

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks for your edits. I am glad to learn more methods!

Comment: @www actually i dont want to be fille by NA but to keep the notation as showed in the example , how can i use tidy::fill? download a package?

Comment: @Maha you need to download the tidyr package.

Comment: @Maha I think I had a typo in my previous comment. The fill function is from the tidyr package.

Comment: @www There is also a problem if no "D" is in the part of the `notation`-vector. Then your answer produces NAs.

Comment: @jogo Thanks for pointing that out. If that is the case, yours and Cath's answers are better.